# Outlook not able to read ToMailID and FromMailID in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-restapi

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder 
= 

ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
int iItemCnt = inboxFolder.Items.Count;
while (iItemCnt != 0)
{
int i = iItemCnt;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)inboxFolder.Items[i]; ;
string MailTo = Convert.ToString(item.To);
string strMailFrom = 
Convert.ToString(item.SenderEmailAddress);
iItemCnt--;
}
```

I am able to get the values of item.To and item.SenderEmailAdress on my local machine.
But when I deploy this on server, the code gets stuck at item.To

I have Microsoft office Outlook 2007 on my local machine as well as on server.[image]

Comment: I mean, it gives me time out error at that line. The screen keeps on loading and give time out.

Comment: It doesn't give any exception, the screen is keeps on loading for hours. I have to forcefully close the application

Comment: I have put logs before and after item.To

Comment: Log.Error("before to mail");

Comment: Screenshot is added.. check now